# Is this nested form field mislabeled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have the following form code

```
<%= f.fields_for resource.paid_account do |pa| %>                                                                     
  <%= pa.collection_select :account_plan_id, @account_plans, :id, :name_with_price %>                                  
<% end %>
```

that generates the following HTML

```
<select id="user_paid_account_account_plan_id" name="user[paid_account][account_plan_id]">
  <option value="2">Lite ($10.00/mo)</option>
  <option value="3">Professional ($20.00/mo)</option>
  <option value="4">Plus ($30.00/mo)</option>
</select>
```

Is `user[paid_account][account_plan_id]` the right name? Shouldn't it be `user[paid_account_attributes][account_plan_id]`?

I ask because this is causing problems on the backend; my `account_plan` record isn't getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this answer is yes. I manually changed the name like this:

```
<%= pa.collection_select :account_plan_id, @account_plans, :id, :name_with_price, {},
                         { name: "user[paid_account_attributes][account_plan_id]" } %>
```

and now it works. Feels like a hack, though, so it seems like there must be a better way to do it.